# No operator "<<" matches these operands error between an object and a string literal

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, string-literals

The code:

```cpp
catch (test& t)
{
    cout << t /*error here*/<</*to here*/ " is not a positive number";
}
```

causes an error:

> No operator "<<" matches these operands

The compiler (c++ 20) says that the error is the `<<` between `t` and `" is not a positive number"`. It might be caused because I overloaded the operator wrong?

Here's my operator `<<` overload:

```cpp
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const test& t)
{
    os << t.getX(); //getX is just a method for getting private member
    return os;
}
```

The entire code, if this isn't enough:

```cpp
class test
{
    int x;
public:
    explicit test(const int _x)
    {
        x = _x;
    }

    int getX() const
    {
        return x;
    }

    friend test& operator << (ostream&, test&);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const test& t)
{
    os << t.getX();
    return os;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    try
    {
        if (n < 0)
        {
            throw test(n);
        }
    }
    catch (test& t)
    {
        cout << t /*error here*/ <</*to here*/ " is not a positive number";
    }
}
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful.  The code provided works just fine on my machine.  I probably didn't put in the bug from the code not provided.

Comment: Your declaration has the wrong prototype. It's also unnecessary since the operator doesn't need to be a friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared one `operator<<`, and defined a different one.  And the wrongly-formed one turns out to be the best match.

Replace* this, which you have declared in your class:

```
test & operator << (ostream & , test & )
```

With this, which you have defined:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const test & t)
```

*Edit:*

*An astute observation from the frequently-astute Mark Ransom:

The bad declaration isn't needed at all.  The function doesn't need to be declared `friend`.  That declaration could simply be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The friend modifier is required if you declare operator overloading as a class/structure member. In the case of declaring globally, it is not necessary indeed!

First option:

```
class test {
  int x;

public:
  explicit test(const int _x) { x = _x; }
  int getX() const { return x; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const test &t) {
    os << t.getX();
    return os;
}
```

Second option:

```
class test {
  int x;

public:
  explicit test(const int _x) { x = _x; }
  int getX() const { return x; }
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const test &t) {
    os << t.getX();
    return os;
  }
};
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that you must ensure access to the members you want to use inside the operator body.

Comment: "*The friend modifier is required if you declare operator overloading as a class/structure member. In the case of declaring globally, it is not necessary indeed!*" - an `operator<<` overload can never be a class member since `ostream` is on the left side, and so the `friend` modifier is needed if the operator wants to access `private`/`protected` class members of the object on the right side.

Comment: This is not true.  `friend` functions are _not_ member functions.  A friend declaration in a class declares that the function has access to that class' private members, despite not being a member function.

Comment: That's not what I meant, I expressed myself badly.  Either way you are completely right.  Thanks.